# Google Translate: não traduzir tags HTML <br>

Tags: html, google, html-tags

Estou a utilizar o tradutor do Google para fazer conjuntos de traduções de documentos HTML em português para inglês. Há alguma maneira de ensinar o Google a perceber que as **tags HTML não são para ser traduzidas**?
Isto sem usar uma conta Google para corrigir todos os casos individualmente (não estou a usar a [API paga](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq))...

Deixo o exemplo:
https://translate.google.com/#pt/en/%3Cbr%3E

A tag `<br>` é diretamente traduzida para *Filmography* por alguma razão em quase todos os casos ([`<br><br>`](https://translate.google.com/#pt/en/%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E) deixa um `<br>`)...
[image: tag <code><br></code> traduzida para Filmography]

Comment: Bem estranho...

Comment: Se você está uma "API" para fazer isto, então você pode usar manipulação de DOM para pegar os textos apenas, traduzi-los e depois subsistir os originais pelos traduzidos

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento certo, eu já estou a recorrer a substituições... Mas seria muito mais simples não ter de o fazer, as tags que estou a usar são bastante curtas, porém são todas substituídas (capitalizadas ou espaçadas) e sinceramente é um pouco absurdo (visto que não se tratam de palavras válidas em qualquer linguagem humana)...

Comment: Eu entendo o absurdo, apenas dei uma sugestão de como contornar o problema

Comment: Outra coisa, sobre o `<br>` aparecer a palavra *Filmography* é devido o google-tradutor ser uma ferramenta comunitária, ou seja, usuários como eu e você podem dar sugestões de traduções melhores e as vezes tais sugestões aparecem para outros usuários e eles acabam "aceitando", pois as vezes ao traduzir longos textos mal percebem as falhas, note que muitos usuários conhecem apenas um idioma, dificilmente se dão conta do erro, uma situação que mostra um "sacanagem" de colabores foi esta: ...

Comment: ... http://dailypicksandflicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/pikachu-batman-google-translate-from-filipino-tagalog-to-english.jpg

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Muito bom... Bem, obrigado pelo esclarecimento! Realmente tem lógica.